# Php recursive function not returning the value

Tags: php, recursion, magento2

I'm using this recursive function to get the grand parent of an option. As far as the needle exists in the array keys, it mean that needle has a parent. When not found, then the needle do not have any parent, so it must return the needle itself.

```
get_parent_need(165,$hay);
function get_parent_need($needle,$hay){
    if(in_array($needle,array_keys($hay))){
        get_parent_need($hay[$needle],array_keys($hay));
    }else{
        return $needle;
    }
}
```

[array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzemS.png)

Comment: Why are you calling `exit`?

Comment: Please provide an example of your array, I think that would help us a lot.

Comment: Was playing with the odds lol, actually I tried to echo the returning value where the function was called , it was returning nothing so I added exit... i edited my question btw

Comment: updated the question with data, array image is also added

Comment: if this will not found needle it will infinite call

Comment: I have added else that if needle not found then must return the needle

Comment: no need to recursive call for this

Comment: So how do I get to the main parent ? I mean from the array, if you see the needle 165 has a parent 175, that has a parent 136, so how do I get there ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use recursion you can search array using

```
function get_parent_need($needle,$hay) {
    if(! in_array( $needle, array_keys( $hay ) ) ){
        return $needle;
    }
    return $hay;
}
```

Comment: No, its not what I need. I need to keep this function running until it find no needle in the array, then I would need that needle to be returned.